# Episode from outer limits or tales from the crypt

Tags: story-identification, tv

This episode contained a scientist who was sick but then cured himself by improving his immune system. Unfortunately, his immune system continued improving to the point that his skin became electric and he grew an eye in the back of his head.

Please help this is driving me nuts!

Comment: do you have an idea of when this might have been / when you watched it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are looking for an episode of the 1990s revival of *The Outer Limits*. Probably this episode titled ["A New Breed"](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0667978/)

> A desperate dying man injects himself with experimental nanobots that can supposedly cure anything. It works, but then his body starts to hideously mutate. He asks his soon-to-be brother-in-law, who invented the nanobots, for help.

It broadly speaking matches your description, and so long as I have remembered the correct episode (memory is sometimes hazy 20 odd years down the line) it should most certainly contain a scene where the protagonist grows eyes in the back of his head.

### YouTube Movies

Comment: Found [a wiki entry](https://theouterlimits.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Breed) that supports this being the correct answer: "The nanobots continue making 'improvements' to Andy, including giving him eyes in the back of his head, bones above his stomach, extra keen hearing, and jellyfish-like stinging tentacles on his skin."